# SQL Server 2000: Server memory / CPU parameters in Query Analyzer

Tags: sql-server, memory, cpu-usage, query-analyzer

**SQL Server 2000:** Is there a way to find out server memory / CPU parameters in Query Analyzer?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're asking for?  When you say "parameters", I think you might mean "settings".  Are you trying to find out information from SP_Configure, or exactly what kind of parameters are you looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

select * from sysperfinfo

it has everything in there that perfmon has. plus make sure you check out all the sql configuration parameters by running sp_configure. also running xp_msver shows a bunch more info about the sql server instance.

between those three i don't know what else you'd want to know.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of. You'll have to look in `perfmon`.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info
```

Sorry, that's 2005 only.  In 2000, you can `xp_cmdshell` out to an external tool or use a COM object through `sp_OA`.